# Как сделать, чтобы в форме после обновления был текст, а при нажатии уходил?

Tags: html, html-form

Как сделать, чтобы в форме после обновления был текст, а при нажатии уходил?

Comment: атрибут placeholder у input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `placeholder`

http://jsfiddle.net/hgKFL/

```
<form action="">
    <p>
        <input type='text' placeholder="Введите текст для поиска">
        <input type="submit" value="Искать">
    </p>
</form>
```

[Атрибут placeholder](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/placeholder)